# Checking for internet connection before form submission

Tags: jquery

I am new to web technologies which made me found most of it difficult. What I am trying to achieve is that when a form is submitted, It should first check for **internet connection** before making an **Ajax** call.

I tried to use **navigator.onLine** this way:

```
if(navigator.onLine == true) {
    //code comes here
} else {
    alert('Internet connection is lost');
    $('#error').append("No internet connection. We could not submit the form");
}
```

Can someone please show me how I can modify my code to suit what I need.

```
$('document').ready(function(){ 
    /* validation */
    $("#licence-form").validate({
        rules:
        { 
            licence: {
                required: true
            },
        },
        messages:
        {
            licence:{
                required: "License key is required"
            },

        },
        submitHandler: licenceForm  
    });  
    /* validation */

    /* submit */
    function licenceForm()
    {       
        var data = $("#licence-form").serialize();

        $.ajax({

            type : 'POST',
            url  : '../includes/b0a012.php',
            data : data,
            beforeSend: function()
            {   
                $("#error").fadeOut();
                $("#btn-login").html('Validating...');
            },
            success :  function(response)
                {                       
                if(response=="yes"){
                    $(".hideit").hide();
                    $(".shows").show();   
                    setTimeout(' window.location.href = "../setup.php"; ',4000);
                }else{      
                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){                        
                        $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center"> <img src="../images/attention.png" width="45" height="40" /> <br/> '+response+'</div>');
                    });

                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `navigator.onLine` property is not really reliable for this purpose. Implementations [differ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) and the status is only updated when an actual connection attempt is made.

Instead, add an `error` handler to the `$.ajax` parameter object:

```
error:  function(xhr, status, error) {
    $(".hideit").hide();
    $(".shows").show();    
    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){                      
          $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center"> <img src="../images/attention.png" width="45" height="40" /> <br/> '+status+' ' + error + '</div>');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

navigator.onLine works differently in different browsers try to check for the internet connection by sending a GET request to the server.By this way you will be sure about the connectivity.

```
    var check_connectivity = {
    is_internet_connected: function() {
        return $.get({
            url: "/app/connectivity/",
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false
        });
    },
    ...
};
```

now

```
check_connectivity.is_internet_connected().done(function() {
   //  you are **probably** online.
   // Your form submission
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //Something went wrong. You may be offline.
});
```